# Cryptic sed command syntax confusion

Tags: regex, unix, sed

Can someone explain, how this sed command works here?

```
pkg info | sed -e 's/\([^.]*\).*/\1/' -e 's/\(.*\)-.*/\1/'
```

This command removes version numbers from packages and prints into stdout like this

```
yajl-2.1.0                     Portable JSON parsing and serialization library in ANSI C
youtube_dl-2018.12.03          Program for downloading videos from YouTube.com
zathura-0.4.1                  Customizable lightweight pdf viewer
zathura-pdf-poppler-0.2.9_1    Poppler render PDF plugin for Zathura PDF viewer
zip-3.0_1                      Create/update ZIP files compatible with PKZIP
zsh-5.6.2                      The Z shell
```

and turns into this

```
yajl
youtube_dl
zathura
zathura-pdf-poppler
zip
zsh
```

But I am having a hard time understanding the parts `([^.]*\).*` `\(.*\)-.*`. I understand the case of `\`, `-e`, `s`. But those wildcards seems very cryptic here.

Comment: The above commands could have been written `sed 's/\..*//;s/-[^-]*$//' file` which perhaps makes them clearer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your regex `([^.]*\).*`, `(` which actually is `\(` is the start of a capturing *group* and then `[^.]*` captures every character except a literal dot and `*` means zero or more, then `\)` is the mark of closing of *group* that we started, then `.*` captures whatever remains after capturing *group1*.

Similar will be the explanation for `\(.*\)-.*` regex, where `\(.*\)` will capture everything greedily in capturing *group* but will stop at last hyphen `-` and then will match hyphen and further `.*` will match remaining text.

To explain with an example, lets take `youtube_dl-2018.12.03`.

Here, `\([^.]*\)` will capture everything until dot, hence it will capture `youtube_dl-2018` and then remaining `.*` will capture `.12.03`. Then it will be replaced by `\1` which means `youtube_dl-2018` will be passed to the next regex `-e 's/\(.*\)-.*/\1/'`.

Then in your second regex, `\(.*\)-.*`, `\(.*\)` will capture  `youtube_dl` and put in *group1* because after that there is a hyphen and `.*` will capture remaining text which is `2018`. And as it is replaced by `\1` hence final text will become `youtube_dl`.

Seeing your data, I believe, you can also simplify your command to this, as your first regex in `sed` command seems redundant. Try this following command and see if it outputs same result?

```
pkg info | sed -e 's/\(.*\)-.*/\1/'
```

You can only use this simplified command, as none of your data contains a `.` before a `-`, otherwise you should use your own command which has two `sed` rules.

Also, on another note, if you use `-r`, (or *-E* for *OS X*), for extended regex, you don't need to escape the parentheses and you can write your regex as,

```
pkg info | sed -r 's/([^.]*).*/\1/' -r 's/(.*)-.*/\1/'
```

Comment: Thanks @ agc for formatting and refining my answer :)

Comment: Understood. Thanks for the explanation :)

Comment: @NikolaiLvovich: If my answer helped you, I would appreciate accepting/upvoting my answer. Thank you.

Comment: Done. sed -E is awesome :)

Answer (score 2):

It is a difficult way for saying:
Remove all substrings starting with a dot or hypen.
The part before the delimiter is matched and remembered.
Alternatives:

```
# Incorrect: removes from first, not last hypen:
#    pkg info | sed 's/[-.].*//'
#    pkg info | cut -d "-" -f1 | cut -d"." -f1
#    pkg info | awk -F "-|[.]" '{print $1}'
# The dot is not needed when you remove the substring starting with the last hypen
pkg info | sed 's/-[^-]*$//'
pkg info | rev | cut -d"-" -f2- | rev
pkg info | awk -F "[.]" '{print $1}' | awk -F "[-]" -vOFS='-' 'NF>1 { NF--;print;}'
```

Comment: Your logic for substitution needs a little correction due to which it will not work correctly for `zathura-pdf-poppler-0.2.9_1` string. Your commands will output `zathura` where as actual output should be `zathura-pdf-poppler`. Hence, the correct statement should be **Remove all substrings starting with "LAST" occurrence of hyphen.** as package names can have hyphen within them and at the same time, hyphen is also the separator for package name and version, which makes the dot as redundant in the regex.

Answer (score 0):

1. Silly invisible-text *GNU* `grep` method that works on the console,
   but which would fail if sent to a file or piped to a filter:

   ```
   pkg info | GREP_COLORS='ms=30;30;30' grep '\-[^-]*\s.*$'
   ```

   ---

   How it works:  `grep` is used to find the last hyphen before a
   space, and everything after that, (*i.e.* everything we don't want
   to see), which `grep` shows in highlighted colors as defined in the
   `GREP_COLORS` environmental variable.  Since the highlight colors
   `30;30;30` is a black font, (on a black background), the unwanted
   text is invisible.

   If the terminal background is already black, `GREP_COLORS='ms=30`
   would be sufficient.
2. `sed` method based on *not* printing the `grep` *regex*:

   ```
   pkg info | sed 's#\(^.*\)\(-[^-]*[[:space:]].*$\)#\1#'
   ```

   ...this method *can* be sent to pipes and filters.  Shorter version using *GNU* `sed`:

   ```
   pkg info | sed 's#\(^.*\)\(-.*\s.*\)#\1#'
   ```

Comment: No idea why this is not working on FreeBSD. Maybe this is GNU grep only feature?

Comment: @NikolaiLvovich, Probably is a *GNU* feature at that, based on a skim of *BSD* [`man sed`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sed&sektion=&n=1).

Comment: Interesting! The sed method is working a little bit.

Comment: @NikolaiLvovich, Re *"working a little bit"*: Please give specifics.

Comment: Few still getting printed this way:

p5-Digest-HMAC-1.03_1          Perl5 interface to HMAC Message

Comment: @NikolaiLvovich, That's quite relevant.  Please revise the question's sample input (and output) to include the problematic `p5-...` line.